# How do I use apply where the function is a polynomial?

Tags: r, apply, data-analysis, lapply

```
est_poly <- function(x,y,slopes,n) {
  x_vals <- seq(x[1],x[2],length.out = n)
  p0 <- y[1]
  p1 <- slopes[1]
  p2 <- (3*(y[2]-y[1])/(x_vals[-1]-x_vals[1])-2*(slopes[1])-slopes[2])/(x_vals[-1]-x_vals[1])
  p3 <- (slopes[1]+slopes[2]-2*(y[2]-y[1])/(x_vals[-1]-x_vals[1]))/(x_vals[-1]-x_vals[1])^2
  x1 <- x_vals[1]
  result <- c()
  for (i in x_vals) {
    poly <- p0+p1*(i-x1)+p2*(i-x1)^2+p3*(i-x1)^3
    result <- append(result, poly[4])
  }
  return(matrix(data = c(x_vals,result), nrow = n))
}
x_eg2 <- c(0,1)
y_eg2 <- c(0,1)
slopes_eg <- c(0,2)
est_poly(x_eg2, y_eg2, slopes_eg, n=5)
```

Hi just want to know how to use apply or lapply to replace the for loop. Should get this as my output.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What are the P0, P1, P2, P3?

Comment: `lapply(x_vals, function(x) p0+p1*(x-x1)+p2*(x-x1)^2+p3*(x-x1)^3)`.

Comment: Hi I've tried this but I get
[1,] 0    numeric,4
[2,] 0.25 numeric,4
[3,] 0.5  numeric,4
[4,] 0.75 numeric,4
[5,] 1    numeric,4

Answer (score 0):

Use a function instead of an expression:

```
x_vals <- c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
x1 <- x_vals[1L]
poly <- function (x) p0 + p1 * (x - x1) + p2 * (x - x1) ^ 2 + p3 * (x - x1) ^ 3
result <- lapply(x_vals, poly)
```

That said, `lapply` returns a *list*; in your case, a vector is probably more appropriate. You can either use `unlist` on the result of `lapply`, or, instead:

```
result <- vapply(x_vals, poly, numeric(1L))
```

If your `poly` function returns multiple values and you want to retain only one, you can either adjust your `poly` function accordingly, or you can nest it into a *further* function which selects the value.

Following your code’s example:

```
result <- vapply(x_vals, \(x) poly(x)[4L], numeric(1L))
```

(In case you’re unfamiliar with it, `\(…)` is a shorthand for `function (…)`.)

Comment: Hi, I've attempted this but I got Error in vapply(x_vals, function(x) p0 + p1 * (x - x1) + p2 * (x - x1)^2 +  : 
  values must be length 0,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 4
 I have edited the question to include more information. If it helps, and you are still willing to help.

Comment: @user19825372 Right, the new code in the question is completely different. t's not clear why your code is using multiple `x_vals` since you are discarding all but one of the result values. — Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: Hi, Ive seen your edit and tried the code out. My poly function does indeed return multiple values though I only expected one and I don't really know how to adjust it or nest it in order to fix it. I've also tried your edited code but I got Error in vapply(x_vals, function(x) poly(x)[4L], numeric()) : 
  values must be length 0,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1 ; but after changing vapply to lapply,  the error resolved itself

Comment: @user19825372 Yeah that was a typo in my code, sorry. It needs to be `numeric(1L)`. But actually do you need the loop/lapply *at all*? Can't you just rely on R's natural vectorisation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see comments for explanations.

```
est_poly <- function(x, y, slopes, n) {
  ## using `seq.int` instead of `seq`
  x_vals <- seq.int(x[1], x[2], length.out=n)  
  p0 <- y[1]
  p1 <- slopes[1]
  p2 <- (3*(y[2] - y[1])/(x_vals[-1] - x_vals[1]) - 2*(slopes[1]) - slopes[2])/(x_vals[-1] - x_vals[1])
  p3 <- (slopes[1] + slopes[2] - 2*(y[2] - y[1])/(x_vals[-1] - x_vals[1]))/(x_vals[-1] - x_vals[1])^2
  x1 <- x_vals[1]
  ## using `vapply` instead of `for` loop
  result <- vapply(x_vals, \(i) (p0 + p1*(i - x1) + p2*(i - x1)^2 + p3*(i - x1)^3)[4], numeric(1L))
  ## alternatively `sapply`, but might be slower 
  # result <- sapply(x_vals, \(i) (p0 + p1*(i - x1) + p2*(i - x1)^2 + p3*(i - x1)^3)[4])
  return(matrix(data=c(x_vals, result), nrow=n))
}

x_eg2 <- c(0, 1)
y_eg2 <- c(0, 1)
slopes_eg <- c(0, 2)
est_poly(x=x_eg2, y=y_eg2, slopes=slopes_eg, n=5)
#      [,1]   [,2]
# [1,] 0.00 0.0000
# [2,] 0.25 0.0625
# [3,] 0.50 0.2500
# [4,] 0.75 0.5625
# [5,] 1.00 1.0000
```